# My component doesn't update data after pushing. Observable doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have the following doubt.

I have 2 components and a service.

one of the components (Component A) displays test records created with a for.

the second component (Component B) is a form for entering more test data.

The data is stored in a collection in the service.

I created an observable to see reflected the changes made to the service in component A.

My problem is that the changes are not updated, but it seems that the push was executed successfully, the data is simply not "refreshed".

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { diagnosticosUsers, User, UserData } from '../shared/user.interface';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {


  public collection = { count: 8, data: [] };
  public collection$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.collection);


  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afs: AngularFirestore, private router:Router, private google: GooglePlus, public platform: Platform, public loadingController: LoadingController) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.collection.count; i++) {
      this.collection.data.push({
        id: i,
        nombre: "Diagnóstico " + i,
        imagen: "https://picsum.photos/id/1" + i + "/200/100",
        descripcion: "Este diagnóstico evalúa el siguiente item " + i,
        precio: i + 1 ,
      });
    }


  }

  

 getCollection(){
    return this.collection;
  }
  getCollectionObservable():Observable<any>{
    return this.collection$;
  }



}
```

**Component A**

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Output } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.service";
import { AlertController } from "@ionic/angular";

@Component({
  selector: "app-diagnosticos",
  templateUrl: "./diagnosticos.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./diagnosticos.page.scss"],
})
export class DiagnosticosPage implements OnInit {
  
  cordova = this.authSvc.cordova;
  desktop = this.authSvc.desktop;
  mobileweb = this.authSvc.mobileweb;
  collection: any ;
  config: any;
  
  constructor(
    private authSvc: AuthService,
    public alertController: AlertController
  ) {}



  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authSvc.collection$.subscribe((value)=>{
      this.collection = {...value};
      console.log(value);
      
    })
    //this.collection= this.authSvc.getCollection();
    this.config = {
      itemsPerPage: 6,
      currentPage: 1,
      totalItems: this.collection.count,
    };


    if (this.cordova == true || this.mobileweb == true) {
      this.config = {
        itemsPerPage: 4,
        currentPage: 1,
        totalItems: this.collection.count,
      };
    } else if (this.desktop == true) {
      this.config = {
        itemsPerPage: 12,
        currentPage: 1,
        totalItems: this.collection.count,
      };
    }
  }

  pageChanged(event) {
    this.config.currentPage = event;
  }

   onEliminate(item: any): void {
    this.authSvc.collection.data.pop(item);
  }
  

  async presentAlertConfirm(item) {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      cssClass: "my-custom-class",
      header: "¡Cuidado!",
      message: "Si elimina un diagnóstico no lo podrá recuperar y los usuarios no podrán acceder a él nunca más",
      buttons: [
        {
          text: "Cancelar",
          role: "cancel",
          cssClass: "secondary",
          handler: (blah) => {
            console.log("Confirm Cancel: blah");
          },
        },
        {
          text: "Confirmar",
          handler: () => {
            this.onEliminate(item);
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
}
```

**Component B**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-diagnostico-create',
  templateUrl: './diagnostico-create.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./diagnostico-create.page.scss'],
})
export class DiagnosticoCreatePage implements OnInit {
  closeResult = '';
  diagnosticoForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public authSvc: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.diagnosticoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: ['', Validators.required],
      nombre: ['', Validators.required],
      descripcion: ['', Validators.required],
      imagen: ['', Validators.required],
      precio: ['', Validators.required],

    })
  }


    diagnosGuardad(){
      this.authSvc.collection.data.push(this.diagnosticoForm.value);
      //descubrir por qué no se lanza esta función
      this.authSvc.collection$.next({...this.authSvc.collection});
      alert(this.diagnosticoForm.value.nombre);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the problem with the change detection in Angular. I have solved this kind of issue once with [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) of Angular.

Here is what you should do inject ChangeDetectorRef in your test records display component.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
constructer(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef){
}
```

When ever you get notified that array has been updated then you just add the following line after that.

```
//After you get notified that array has been updated
this.cd.detectChanges();
```

Hope this works if not revert back I will another solution.

Comment: ```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authSvc.collection$.subscribe((value)=>{
      this.collection = {...value};
      console.log(value);
    });
}```

You mean to do it this way?

Comment: Yes after you update this.collection array then add this.cd.detectChanges(); this would hard reload the angular component for Array changes :)

Comment: Then try doing using push the angular change detection will work on push where as you are directly assigning the array. write a for loop and push every item in value to collections and check once.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
this.authSvc.collection.data.push(this.diagnosticoForm.value);
```

Try this:

```
this.authSvc.collection.data = [...this.authSvc.collection.data, this.diagnosticoForm.value];
```

With that way you create a new array and you let Angular to understand that something has changed, without triggering manual the Change Detection.